# How to update a textbox on Form from a click on a button on a User Control

Tags: vb.net

I need update the text of a textbox when I do click on a button on a user control.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare an event in the user control and have the button's Click event raise it:

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Public Event MyButtonClick As EventHandler(Of MyButtonClickEventArgs)

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent MyButtonClick(Me, New MyButtonClickEventArgs("nobugz"))
  End Sub

  Public Class MyButtonClickEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Private mText As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)
      mText = text
    End Sub
    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
      Get
        Return mText
      End Get
    End Property
  End Class

End Class
```

Now the form that hosts the user control can subscribe to the event and update the text box as needed:

```
  Private Sub UserControl11_MyButtonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As WindowsApplication1.UserControl1.MyButtonClickEventArgs) Handles UserControl11.MyButtonClick
    TextBox1.Text = e.Text
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

And how I send a string from the user control to the form?

I need send data from user control to thr form and read it in the textbox. For example:

```
Private Sub UserControl11_MyButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UserControl11.MyButtonClick
    TextBox1.Text = e.mystring
End Sub
```